# Looking for a patch utility can generate exe file

Tags: diff, patch

I need a patch utility which generates an exe file from the differences of 2 binaries. Then, end-users only need to run that exe file, point to the old version and apply patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found it on my own. It's [diablo2oo2's Universal Patcher - [dUP]](http://diablo2oo2.di.funpic.de/dup.html)

Comment: Dead link, but it's still in the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20121102090934/http://diablo2oo2.di.funpic.de/dup.html, including a working download

Answer (score 1):

I've used [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/) or [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) before for very similar purposes.  Unlike the standard `diff` tool, these tools will work properly with binary files.  (As your post implies Windows, there are Windows ports available for each of these - or you can use Cygwin.)

These tools won't create a patching `exe` for you, however.  You could still use these tools to get the difference of the binary files, then package everything into an exe to your requirements.  I'm not personally and specifically aware of any tool that does all of what you're looking for - but I believe they exist, and most of them are probably commercial products - and giving specific product recommendations is off-topic for SO.